# What all jar files should i include to use stanford parser in my project?

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I tried creating a new project to work on stanford parsers.

I have included stanford-postagger.jar and stanford-parser-2012-05-22-models.jar to the project.
is there anything else that I should add?

I am not able to use LexicalizedParser. I am getting an error : `LexicalizedParser cannot be resolved to a type" in the line ...`

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
```

I am using eclipse IDE.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 2):

LexicalizedParser is in stanford-corenlp.jar